# cakephp: $this->Auth->allow

Tags: cakephp, authentication

When I click the `Enroll Now` button under admissions on my navigation bar, `\merry_flowers\views\students\add.ctp` should display.
Instead, the login page is getting displayed. 
Does anyone know on what I'm doing wrong?

The following is my `app_controller.php` for the project:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
var $components=array('Auth','Session','Cookie');

function beforeFilter(){
  if (isset($this->Auth)){
        $this->Auth->userModel='MerryParent';
        $this->Auth->loginAction=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'login');
                    //var_dump($this->data);
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'report_card');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'register');
        $this->Auth->deny('report_card');
        $this->Auth->authorize='controller';
      }
   else
        $this->Session->setFlash('Auth has not been set');  
}

function isAuthorized(){
    return true;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One gotcha is if your `StudentsController` has a `beforeFilter`, you'll need to call `parent::beforeFilter` or that Auth setup won't happen.

I'd also note the [caveat](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1265/AuthComponent-Variables#authorize-1275) for using `authorize = 'controller'`; "Remember that [isAuthorized] will be checked after you have already passed the basic authentication check against the user model.". Given that you have `$this->Auth->allow('*')`, auth should be skipped entirely, so I'd look for a more fundamental mistake such as the beforeFilter override.

Unfortunately nothing stands out in your pasted code. Auth problems usually involve facepalm solutions in my experience :)

Comment: hi, as u had suggested, i added parent::beforeFilter() to the beforeFilter in StudentsController and now everything works fine. Thanks a lot!:)